# itext7 html2pdf is not able to render vector images

Tags: pdf, c#-4.0, vector, itext7

We have .net Web API to generate pdf based on certain parameters, this pdf will have images in .eps and .ai (vector images). We are using itext7 html2pdf and passing html as string to the method ConvertToPdf but it's not able to recognize those vector images. 
Need help to add vector image in pdf to retain the image quality in pdf and the file size should not increase more than 2MB.

Please find code snippet:

```
public string GenerateHtmlToPdf(string html , string fileName)
{
    //generate pdf from html using iText7
    try
    {
        string filePath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filePath"];
        FileStream finalPdfPath = new FileStream(filePath + "\\" + fileName + ".pdf", FileMode.Create);
        string finalPath = filePath + fileName + ".pdf";
        PdfFontFactory.RegisterDirectory(FONTDIR);
        var NewTransportBold = PdfFontFactory.CreateRegisteredFont("NewTransport-Bold", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
        var NewTransportNormal = PdfFontFactory.CreateRegisteredFont("NewTransport-Regular", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
        var NewTransportLight = PdfFontFactory.CreateRegisteredFont("NewTransport-Light", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);

        HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(html, finalPdfPath);
        return finalPath;
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        var exists = File.Exists("File already exist on desktop");
        return "file exist";
    }
    //end
}
```

Comment: Use PDF as the image format

Comment: a) I can't really see your question. StackOverflow is a platform where people ask and answer *questions*. b) iText does not support `.eps` or `.ai` image formats.

Comment: I am looking for help to add vector image in pdf using itext7. I am getting vector image from client as .ai/.eps file so wanted to know if there is any mechanism to use these files directly or by converting them in other vector image format so that once pdf is ready the image quality would be intact.

Answer (score 0):

As for pdfs, it is not possible to add svg formats.Hence the svg image would have to be added to the document where the html was set separately.For this a NuGet package named [Svg](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Svg/) is used.

```
public void AddSVG(string resourceLocator, float x, float y, int page, int scalePresent = 100)
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    MemoryStream memoryFile = new MemoryStream(webClient.DownloadData(resourceLocator));
    SvgDocument memorySVGFile = SvgDocument.Open<SvgDocument>(memoryFile);//get the img as svg doc
    var imgconv = memorySVGFile.Draw(3000, 3000);
    MemoryStream imgStream = new MemoryStream();
    imgconv.Save(imgStream, ImageFormat.Png);//convert svg doc in to a png and save in a mem stream
    Image img = new Image(ImageDataFactory.Create(imgStream.ToArray()));  //create itext image object from byte array        
    img.SetFixedPosition(page,x, y, 550);
    doc.Add(img);
    memoryFile.Close();
}
```

here the string resourceLocator is the path to the svg. And "doc." is the pdf document where the html was converter to a pdf document.